# Akka http read and parse uploaded excel file

Tags: scala, akka-http

Say, if I have an excel file (size range from 0 ~ 100MB) which needs to be uploaded from client side to server, then it'll get parsed. How to do that with Akka-Http ? I read the [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html), it seems they only support json and csv format.

Besides, from the view of server side, do I have to parse the file only after it has been uploaded or I can parse one data entry a time as long as it's available during the process of uploading ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel apart from it being the source file?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald , I need to parse the content after receiving at server side ( using Apache POI) . What I'm not confident is the process of handling the byte stream transfering when using Akka-Http.

Comment: How could an Excel user with no knowledge of Akka-Http or Scala answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about an excel file as opposed to any other file type.

**File Directive**

There already exists directives to respond to get requests with a file:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import java.io.File
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes

val easyRoute : Route = 
  getFromFile(File("/path/to/excelFile.xls"),
              ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`)
```

**Manual Creation**

You can use [file io](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-io.html#Streaming_File_IO) to create a `Source` of the excel file as a `ChunkStreamPart`:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.ChunkStreamPart

val excelFile = Paths get "example.xls"

val fileChunkSource : () => Source[ChunkStreamPart, _] = 
  () => FileIO fromPath excelFile
```

This file source can then be used to create an HttpEntity:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity

val entity : () => HttpEntity = 
  () => HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, fileSource())
```

Which can then be the entity of an `HttpResponse`:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse

val excelResponse : () => HttpResponse = 
  () => HttpResponse(entity = entity())
```

This response can be part of a standard [route](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/introduction.html#routing-dsl-for-http-servers):

```
val route = 
  get {
    path(/ "excelFile") {
      complete(excelResponse())
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can also use `HttpEntity.apply` directly which is a bit simpler than going through `ChunkStreamPart.apply`.